# Cant Access Session In Another Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, passport-local

i just started working on Passport local and i am new to it so here's the problem
When I Console.log() after Authentication successfully, Session is there,

```
app.use('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.session);
        res.redirect('/home');
    });
```

Output Of Console.Log

```
   Session {
          cookie:
           { path: '/',
             _expires: 2017-08-03T19:42:58.728Z,
             originalMaxAge: 14400000,
             httpOnly: true,
             secure: false },
          passport: { user: '5909a6c0' } }
```

But when i console.log in /Home page or Using this function in App.js It is Undefined, session is not saved.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    if (req.user)
        return next();
    else
        return res.status(401).json({
            error: 'User not authenticated'
        })

}
```

Output of Console.log now,

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2017-05-08T19:43:10.503Z,
     originalMaxAge: 14400000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false } }
```

I Appreciate Your help